# Are these limitations still there when using JPA with Cloud SQL?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-sql

I doubt it but still want to confirm if these limitations are still there or not when using JPA with Cloud SQL.

> ### Unsupported Features of JPA 1.0
>
> The following features of the JPA interface are not supported by the
>   App Engine implementation:
>
> - Owned many-to-many relationships, and unowned relationships. You can implement unowned relationships using explicit Key values, though type checking is not enforced in the API.
> - "Join" queries. You cannot use a field of a child entity in a filter when performing a query on the parent kind. Note that you can test the parent's relationship field directly in a query using a key.
> - Aggregation queries (group by, having, sum, avg, max, min).
> - Polymorphic queries. You cannot perform a query of a class to get instances of a subclass. Each class is represented by a separate entity kind in the datastore.

Comment: They never were there for MySQL usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those limitations apply to JPA 1.0 for [*Datastore*](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview). Cloud SQL is using native MySQL driver in App Engine so JPA should work properly (there are examples for [EclipseLink](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-cloudsql-native-mysql-eclipselink-jpa-demo-java), [DataNucleus](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-cloudsql-native-mysql-datanucleus-jpa-demo-java) and [Hibernate](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-cloudsql-native-mysql-hibernate-jpa-demo-java)).

Comment: where does it say that its only specific to datastore, even examples are simple one, no aggregation

Comment: From [1]: "The App Engine Java SDK includes an implementation of JPA 1.0 for the App Engine **datastore**."