# Don't understand Google endpoints with JPA/JDO for Google SQL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, jdbc, google-cloud-sql

I have been trying to connect my Google endpoint to Google SQL.

I am unsure about the limitations regarding JPA/JDO though. Unsupported features are mentioned such as, no aggregation queries, polymorphic queries, joins.

JPA/JDO seems focused on the datastore, removing some of the functionality with relational databases. What should I then use to handle that functionality?

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: If you are using an SQL datastore then clearly JDO and JPA *do* allow joins, as a quick glance at basic JDOQL and JPQL docs would tell you. Then you can update your question with what you really mean perhaps

Comment: Hi @Neil. I feel confused about this, because there are alot of places I read about the unsupported futures of JPA/JDO. Such as aggregation queries, polymorphic queries etc. I want to use Google SQL, are those limitations only for the datastore? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832235/are-these-limitations-still-there-when-using-jpa-with-cloud-sql?rq=1)

Comment: Yes @cfl those are limitations of the actual implementation. If you are usign cloudSQL you should be fine.

Comment: They are NOT limitations of the implementation ... they are limitations of the DATASTORE ... GAE/Datastore. You're not using that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDO/JPA do support those features. What you have been reading about are the limitations in the underlying implementation (datastore) that works completely different from a relational db.